# On Line Reference: All the Built in function of C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Where can I see all the built in function of C#?

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't have any "built in functions" as such.

If you mean "types in the .NET framework" then [MSDN is your friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx).

Comment: @Yuriy: That's an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Hit "F1" in Visual Studio. The documentation is a great reference.

Comment: Googling with MSDN as one of your search params will be much faster and more effective. F1 stinks.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: Well yeah, of course. But it still contains documentation of all the library functions. Just one more way to do things.

Comment: The documentation itself isn't too bad and actually seems to be getting better with each .NET release but my point is that there are better paths to the final info than M$'s. I've noticed years ago that Google does a much better job indexing MSDN than Microsoft. Sad but true and good to know.

Answer (score 0):

If using Visual Studio ide, you can also use the object browser to inspect all manner of assemblies. Or reflector for that matter.

Answer (score -1):

That would be an empty list. There are no functions defined in C#. C# is object oriented, it has no "native" functions as part of the langauge.